# What is the proper way to make your url "nicer"?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

recently i have tried to build some MVC application without any framework to understand MVC pattern better. Till now i have resolved every problem i have had BUT....
Pretty common thing is to make your URL looks "nicer"

For example 
 `www.somesite.com/controller/method`

instead of 
 `www.somesite.com/index.php?c=1&m=2`.

i achieved this simply with htacces by aiming it to a variable.

in htaccess...
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]`

This works perfectly fine until someone tries to rewrite variable "url".

 Basically if someone types `www.somesite.com/controller/method?url=1`
my Application will pop up an error page because i am parsing everything after `/` and calling specific controllers and methods by its name (or popping up an error page if that doesnt exists).

So i would like to know if there is a better way to do this or way to avoid this behaviour
Thanks :)

### EDIT

In last few hours i tried to find a better solutions. I thought i could put my url into Enviromental variable instead of into get variable. 
So i experimented with commands like 
 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [E=URL:$1,QSA]`

unfortunately `$_SERVER["URL"]` is blank......
i would be really happy if someone could help me with this piece of code :) Thanks

### EDIT 2

Okay to make it clear i'll add few examples.
My current htacces looks like this
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]`
So if someone goes to `www.somesite.com/foo/bar`
i will check `$_GET["url"]` and then explode it `explode("/", filter_var(rtrim($_GET["url"], "/"), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL))`
Now i have array which looks like `[0=>foo 1=>bar]` 
That means in my code that i will try to call controller called `foo` and then method in this class called `bar`
In case that the user will try to acces `www.somesite.com/foo/bar/fee/faa`, `fee` and `faa` will pass as a parameters to method `bar` in class `foo`.

So this was just example how does this work. My problem is as i said when someone tries to acces lets say `www.somesite.com/foo?url=0`. Then my script will try to handle `$_GET["url"]` and the result wont be `foo` but `0` because of `?url=0` rewrites the value of `url` which was originaly set in my .htacces. So my scripts will try to call controller called `0` and if that doesnt exists itt will popup `error404`. I have already tried to ignore this specific variable via `QUERY_STRING` in htacces but this seems to me like a stupid solution. For now i would like to stick with setting evniromental variable instead of get variable or if there is some better way to achieve this :) Thanks

Comment: How have you managed to convert a specific issue with a specific implementation into a general discussion about design patterns? ;-P

Comment: I hoped this would be clear enough to understand it and answer :D :) I usually don't ask about bugs etc. because i am not good at explaining things like that and i enjoy solving problems on my own but i struggled with this one for some time now and i couldn't find answer. So i tried :( If this is not clear i don't know what to do then...:D

Comment: Can you add examples of valid URL edits which fail due to .htaccess? How does `method` link to `c=1` and `m=2`, and how many possible methods are there?  
Can you add the code that shows how you are parsing the `url` section, or is this code in every page of your app? Would URL editing by an acceptable solution? **Edit** if you prefer to solve yourself there are several good [htaccess generators like this one](http://htaccessredirect.net) and a good [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current set-up relies on `$_GET` to obtain core information but, as you've faced, that variable is populated from user input so anyone can mess with your routing, even inadvertently.

A typical Apache configuration for a custom router looks like this ([this snippet is from CakePHP/2.x](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/app/webroot/.htaccess)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As you can see is doesn't add GET variables of its own, it merely lets existing ones to pass through. Original URL is right there inside `$_SERVER`, you don't need to instruct Apache to copy it into the redirected URL.

I understand you want `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but you can peek inside the array with the usual methods: `print_r($_SERVER)`, `var_dump($_SERVER)`, `phpinfo()`...